# how to iterate a map in lightning component to match parent and child id?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, map, aura

I want to display IDF records and related Review Records in a List View using Lightning Component.below i am attaching my code.

**MY Class:**

```
public with sharing class BulkdataUpdate
{
 // getting list of IDFS
@AuraEnabled
public static list <Invention_Disclosure_New__c> fetchIDFs(Id IDFId) 
{
    list < Invention_Disclosure_New__c > returnIDFList = new List < Invention_Disclosure_New__c > ();
    List < Invention_Disclosure_New__c > lstidf = [SELECT Name, Title__c, Hierarchy__c,Hierarchy__r.Name, Primary_Inventor__c,
    Primary_Inventor__r.Name, Disclosure_Status__c, Submitted_Date__c,Invention_Country__c,
    Internal_Counsel__c,Disclosure_State__c From Invention_Disclosure_New__c WHERE Disclosure_Status__c='Submitted']; 
    system.debug('lstidf :'+lstidf); 
    for (Invention_Disclosure_New__c idf: lstidf)
    {
        returnIDFList.add(idf);
    }
    return returnIDFList;
}
 // Trying to map
@AuraEnabled   
public static string IDFReviewRecords1() 
{
    Map<Id, Invention_Disclosure_New__c> myidfMap = new Map<Id, Invention_Disclosure_New__c>();
    Map<Invention_Disclosure_New__c, List<IDF_Review__c>> myMapwithID = new Map<Invention_Disclosure_New__c, List<IDF_Review__c>>();
    List < Invention_Disclosure_New__c > lstidf = [SELECT Name, Title__c, Hierarchy__c,Hierarchy__r.Name, Primary_Inventor__c,
    Primary_Inventor__r.Name, Disclosure_Status__c, Submitted_Date__c,Invention_Country__c,
    Internal_Counsel__c,Disclosure_State__c From Invention_Disclosure_New__c WHERE Disclosure_Status__c='Submitted'];
    for(Invention_Disclosure_New__c idf : lstidf)
    {
        myidfMap.put(idf.id,idf);
    }
    list<IDF_Review__c> idfrev =[SELECT Id,Base_Invention_Disclosure__c,Final_Rating__c FROM IDF_Review__c WHERE Base_Invention_Disclosure__r.id IN:myidfMap.keyset()];
    system.debug('-------'+idfrev);
    for(IDF_Review__c idr : idfrev)
    {
        if(myidfMap.containsKey(idr.Base_Invention_Disclosure__c))
        {
            Invention_Disclosure_New__c IDF =  myidfMap.get(idr.Base_Invention_Disclosure__c);
            List<IDF_Review__c> temp = myMapwithID.get(IDF);
            if(temp == null) 
            {                   
                myMapwithID.put(IDF, new List<IDF_Review__c>{idr});
            } 
            else 
            {
                temp.add(idr);
            }
        }
    }
    system.debug(JSON.serialize(myMapwithID));
    return JSON.serialize(myMapwithID);
}
```

**MY Controller**

```
({
loadIDFrecordList: function(component, event, helper) {
 helper.onLoad(component, event);
 },

fetchMapCtrl: function(component, event, helper) {
    //call apex class method 
    var action = component.get('c.IDFReviewRecords');
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        //store response state 
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            // create a empty array for store map keys 
            var arrayOfMapKeys = [];
            // store the response of apex controller (return map)     
            var StoreResponse = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('StoreResponse' + StoreResponse);
            // set the store response[map] to component attribute, which name is map and type is map.   
            component.set('v.fullMap', StoreResponse);
            alert(Json.stringfy(response.getReturnValue()))
            for (var singlekey in StoreResponse) {
                arrayOfMapKeys.push(singlekey);
            }
            // Set the all list of keys on component attribute, which name is lstKey and type is list.     
            component.set('v.lstKey', arrayOfMapKeys);
        }
    });
    // enqueue the Action   
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

**MY Component:**

```
<aura:component controller="BulkdataUpdate" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="ListOfIDF" type="Invention_Disclosure_New__c[]" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.loadIDFrecordList}"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchMapCtrl}"/>
<aura:attribute name="fullMap" type="map"/>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.fullMap}" var="idfrev">
    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!idfrev.Final_Rating__c}">{!idfrev.Final_Rating__c}</div>
</aura:iteration>
```

Help me to get out of this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Don't think component markup supports maps so think you will need to set the data up as a list where each item is the disclosure and its list of inventions. Then use a pair of nested aura:iteration.

Comment: definitely no chance with maps in aura:iteration. you must go with lists, at least for now.